# using too many booleans

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to do this?

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    bool t01 = line.Model.ToLower() == model;
    bool t02 = line.Authority.ToLower() != "unknown";
    bool t101 = line.Type.ToLower() == "adcn";
    bool t102 = line.Type.ToLower() == "adcn/adv";
    bool t103 = line.Type.ToLower() == "bn";
    bool t104 = line.Type.ToLower() == "book";
    bool t105 = line.Type.ToLower() == "cancel";
    bool t106 = line.Type.ToLower() == "cir";
    bool t107 = line.Type.ToLower() == "coord sht";
    bool t108 = line.Type.ToLower() == "cre";
    bool t109 = line.Type.ToLower() == "ddr";
    bool t110 = line.Type.ToLower() == "dl";

    if (t01 && t02)
        if ((t101 || t102 || t103 || t104 || t105 || t106 || t107 || t108 || t109 || t110))
            Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

It actually goes up to t139. Clipped it for brevity.

Comment: You need to send this to [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Comment: rethink how you are solving the problem at hand.

Comment: @Luwe: Unless it's in the C# tag, then Jon Skeet will always answer. :)

Comment: You should use string.Compare("", "", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) instead of ToLower for string comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] validTypes = new string[] { "adcn", "adcn/adv", "bn", "book" /*, ...*/ };

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    bool t01 = line.Model.ToLower() == model;
    bool t02 = line.Authority.ToLower() != "unknown";

    if(t01 && t02 && validTypes.Contains(line.Type.ToLower())
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: While my (now accepted) answer is a good quick fix that does the job, I have to defer to Jon Skeet's answer for a **proper** solution. His answer is far more thorough and orders of magnitude more efficient.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you need a `HashSet<string>` for the types:

```
static readonly HashSet<string> ValidTypes = new HashSet<string>
    (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    "adcn", "adcn/adv", "bn" ...
};

if (line.Model.Equals(model, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    !line.Authority.Equals("unknown", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    validTypes.Contains(line.Type))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

That will also be faster than comparing the string for each item individually. Note that although I've used `OrdinalIgnoreCase` in the above, that *may* not be what you really want - you may want `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

(Note that lower-casing strings in order to perform a case-insensitive comparison is a bad idea - particularly if you're just using the default locale to do it in. For example, if you lower-case "MAIL" and your current locale is Turkish, you *won't* get "mail".)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

or just plain LINQ

```
var types = new List<string>{ "adcn", "adcn/adv" }; // etc
if (types.Any(t => t == line.Type.ToLower()))
{
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Considering your example:

```
var types = new List<string>{ "adcn", "adcn/adv" }; // etc

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (types.Any(t => t == line.Type.ToLower()))
    {
         Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Or maybe

```
var types = new List<string>{ "adcn", "adcn/adv" }; // etc

foreach (var line in lines.Where(line => types.Any(t => t == line.Type.ToLower())))
{
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: this will not reduce the no. of comparisons in if statement

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by better?  Just off the top of my head, you are evaluating 139 conditions, and then writing the line to the console if any of them are true.  It would be more efficient to short circuit if the first one (or the third one, or the fourth, etc) was true and not bother evaluating the rest.

You can do this by storing the evaluation functions in a list:

```
var cases = new List<Func<Line>>();
cases.Add(l => l.Model.ToLower() == model); //Be careful of the closure here
cases.Add(l => l.Authority.ToLower() != "unknown"); 
... etc ...
```

and then evaluating the functions in order for each line, exiting early if the current function returns true:

```
if (cases.Any(c=>c(line)))
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```